# How can I find a frontier line that separates two different colors on an image with the goal of splitting the image along that line?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing, hough-transform

I am working on a video and image treatment on an application in chemistry. The application consists of tracking the orientation of a bicolored particle over time. As an input, I have the video of a particle, which I split into images that I preprocessed using OpenCV.

In order to track the orientation of the particle, I have to first find a line which can separate the black part of the particle from the white part, and use this to track the angle over time.

My original input image :

[image: Input image]

To preprocess my image I used Canny [Detection](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_canny/py_canny.html), the [Find contour](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) method to detect the desired particle contour, used a mask to unify the background and treated the image so that it would have a clear black-white separation.

Later on, I tried using [OpenCV's HoughLines method](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html) (picture down and with the code mentioned on the website) but clearly the line used does not split my particle's colors.

Therefore, I want to know if there is a way to change the orientation of my line or to find the frontier line which can (most closely) separate the black and white color within my particle.

If I solve this, all I will have to do is to apply this to all frames of the video and track the angle that this supposed ''frontier line'' forms with the horizontal.

[image: A failed attempt to draw a line separating the black and white in my particle using OpenCV's HoughLines]

EDIT: I am adding an 'expected' line that I drew to give a clearer idea about what I mean by splitting the black from the white :

[image: Expected result (approximately)]

Comment: Use canny edge detection perhaps. But please post an original input image so we can see your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did use Canny Edge Detection at first when treating my original image (cf. edits), is it possible to reuse it to solve my current problem? Also, as requested, I included my original image.

Comment: Cool question! Can you share some video for better understanding please - Dropbox, Google Drive or somesuch? Thank you.

Comment: This is just an update as regards to how I solved the problem. I ended up not using any "line separation" per se, but have used a combination of different processing algorithms (canny, masks, etc...) and isolated the black part of my particle. Using coordinate of the center of the particle and the coordinates of the center of the black part of the particle (both of which evolve overtime), I solved the problem using simple trigonometry.